# Convert '\x00' to ASCII in Python 3

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, hex, ctypes

I currently have the following operation:

```
a = 'cat\x00  '
```

The format is in unicode (the default Python 3 string format). I wish to convert it to ASCII. So far I have tried this:

```
a = bytes(a, 'ascii')
print(a)

OUT: b'cat\x00   '
```

Using the byes command is converting 'a' into a raw string and not carrying out the '\x' escape character. Is there a way I can convert 'a' to ASCII after executing the hex conversion?

I need the value of 'a' for ctypes:

```
ct.c_char_p(a)
```

Comment: What do you expect to see? NUL is non-printable character.

Comment: I wish to send b'cat\x00   ' as ASCII into ctypes. ctypes can only handle ASCII codes but Python 3 can perform string manipulations in unicode. Hence I do not know how to effectively convert it to ASCII for ctypes to work on. All the strings like 'a' will have the same length when being sent to a C library using ctypes. The 0x00 at the end of the string will basically tell the C codes to ignore anything after that value.

Comment: ctypes isn't limited to ASCII. `c_char_p` is a pointer to any null-terminated byte string. That could be any single-byte or multibyte character encoding that doesn't have embedded nulls -- such as ASCII, Latin-1, a Windows codepage, or UTF-8. For a wide-character string (UTF-16 or UTF-32), use `c_wchar_p`. Please update your question with the prototype of the C function you're trying to call.

Comment: I do not have access to the C codes at the moment. I do have the ctypes code in Python 2 and that worked. I am simply trying to translate the codes to Python 3. The Python 2 code basically took in 'cat\x00' as a variable for `c_char_p`.

Comment: Small correction. I am using C++ codes. Not C codes. And I am using c_types to read the functions from a DLL file.

Comment: If the C function takes a `char *`, encode the Python string as UTF-8, e.g. `a = 'cat'.encode('utf-8')`. Also, don't manually add a null at the end of the string. Internally Python uses null-terminated strings, and ctypes passes a pointer to this internal string buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ct.c_char_p(a.encode('UTF-8'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass `b'cat'` or `'cat'.encode()`.  Both will pass a null-terminated byte string to a `c_char_p` ctypes parameter.  You don't need to add a null yourself.

Example to call `void func(const char* s)` in `some.dll`:

```
from ctypes import *
dll = CDLL('some.dll')
dll.func.argtypes = [c_char_p]
dll.func.restype = None

dll.func(b'cat')
dll.func('cat'.encode())
```